# How can I analyze a confusion matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

When I print out scikit-learn's confusion matrix, I receive a very huge matrix. I want to analyze what are the true positives, true negatives etc. How can I do so?
This is how my confusion matrix looks like. I wish to understand this better.

```
[[4015  336    0 ...,    0    0    2]
 [ 228 2704    0 ...,    0    0    0]
 [   4    7   19 ...,    0    0    0]
 ..., 
 [   3    2    0 ...,    5    0    0]
 [   1    1    0 ...,    0    0    0]
 [  13    1    0 ...,    0    0   11]]
```

Comment: btw, If you want to practice your ability to analyze confusion matrices, there's a quiz website here: https://www.mattobrien.me/

Answer (score 7):

IIUC, your question is undefined. "False positives", "true negatives" - these are terms that are defined only for binary classification. Read more about the definition of a [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix).

In this case, the confusion matrix is of dimension *N X N*. Each diagonal represents, for entry *(i, i)* the case where the prediction is *i* and the outcome is *i* too. Any other off-diagonal entry indicates some mistake where the prediction was *i* and the outcome is *j*. There is no meaning to "positive" and "negative in this case.

You can find the diagnoal elements easily using [`np.diagonal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html), and, following that, it is easy to sum them. The sum of wrong cases is the sum of the matrix minus the sum of the diagonal.

Answer (score 2):

Terms like *true positive*,*false positive*, etc. refer to **binary classification**. Whereas the dimensionality of your confusion matrix is greater then two. So you can talk only about the number of observations known to be in group i but predicted to be in group j (definition of confusion matrix).

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1: Binary Classification**

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix as cm
import pandas as pd

y_test = [1, 0, 0]
y_pred = [1, 0, 0]
confusion_matrix=cm(y_test, y_pred)

list1 = ["Actual 0", "Actual 1"]
list2 = ["Predicted 0", "Predicted 1"]
pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix, list1,list2)
```

[image]

**Approach 2: Multiclass Classification**

While sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix provides a numeric matrix, you can generate a 'report' using the following:

```
import pandas as pd
y_true = pd.Series([2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
y_pred = pd.Series([0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2])

pd.crosstab(y_true, y_pred, rownames=['True'], colnames=['Predicted'], margins=True)
```

which results in:

```
Predicted  0  1  2  All
True                   
0          3  0  0    3
1          0  1  2    3
2          2  1  3    6
All        5  2  5   12
```

This allows us to see that:

1. The diagonal elements show the number of correct classifications for each class: 3, 1 and 3 for the classes 0, 1 and 2.
2. The off-diagonal elements provides the misclassifications: for example, 2 of the class 2 were misclassified as 0, none of the class 0 were misclassified as 2, etc.
3. The total number of classifications for each class in both `y_true` and `y_pred`, from the "All" subtotals

This method also works for text labels, and for a large number of samples in  the dataset can be extended to provide percentage reports.